# Multiple Mutable Borrows from Struct Hashmap

Tags: rust

Running into an ownership issue when attempting to reference multiple values from a HashMap in a struct as parameters in a function call. Here is a PoC of the issue.

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Resource {
    map: HashMap<String, String>,
}

impl Resource {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Resource {
            map: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn load(&mut self, key: String) -> &mut String {
        self.map.get_mut(&key).unwrap()
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Initialize struct containing a HashMap.
    let mut res = Resource {
        map: HashMap::new(),
    };
    res.map.insert("Item1".to_string(), "Value1".to_string());
    res.map.insert("Item2".to_string(), "Value2".to_string());

    // This compiles and runs.
    let mut value1 = res.load("Item1".to_string());
    single_parameter(value1);
    let mut value2 = res.load("Item2".to_string());
    single_parameter(value2);

    // This has ownership issues.
    // multi_parameter(value1, value2);
}

fn single_parameter(value: &String) {
    println!("{}", *value);
}

fn multi_parameter(value1: &mut String, value2: &mut String) {
    println!("{}", *value1);
    println!("{}", *value2);
}
```

Uncommenting `multi_parameter` results in the following error:

```
28 |     let mut value1 = res.load("Item1".to_string());
   |                      --- first mutable borrow occurs here
29 |     single_parameter(value1);
30 |     let mut value2 = res.load("Item2".to_string());
   |                      ^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
...
34 |     multi_parameter(value1, value2);
   |                     ------ first borrow later used here
```

It would technically be possible for me to break up the function calls (using the single_parameter function approach), but it would be more convenient to pass the
variables to a single function call.

For additional context, the actual program where I'm encountering this issue is an SDL2 game where I'm attempting to pass multiple textures into a single function call to be drawn, where the texture data may be modified within the function.

Comment: The usual solution for interior mutability is `RefCell`; seems like an ok solution here. But why do you need these resources to be mutable?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo In my actual program, the resources are textures/images that will be drawn to the screen within the function call. However, certain properties such as the texture color tint may be modified or set within the function. Thus, they need to be mutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible, without resorting to unsafe code or interior mutability at least. There is no way for the compiler to know if two calls to `load` will yield mutable references to different data as it cannot always infer the value of the `key`. In theory, mutably borrowing both `res.map["Item1"]` and `res.map["Item2"]` would be fine as they would refer to different values in the map, but there is no way for the compiler to know this at compile time.

The easiest way to do this, as already mentioned, is to use a structure that allows interior mutability, like `RefCell`, which typically enforces the memory safety rules at run-time before returning a borrow of the wrapped value. You can also work around the borrow checker in this case by dealing with `mut` pointers in unsafe code:

```
pub fn load_many<'a, const N: usize>(&'a mut self, keys: [&str; N]) -> [&'a mut String; N] {
    // TODO: Assert that keys are distinct, so that we don't return
    // multiple references to the same value

    keys.map(|key| self.load(key) as *mut _)
        .map(|ptr| unsafe { &mut *ptr })
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c97a78d26206107d8ea97ee89e383312)

The `TODO` is important, as this assertion is the only way to ensure that the safety invariant of only having one mutable reference to any value at any time is upheld.

It is, however, almost always better (and easier) to use a known safe interior mutation abstraction like `RefCell` rather than writing your own unsafe code.